# Synchronous javascript call to MVC 4 Controller action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm writing piece of code, and I need some functions to be executed sequential, I used ajax call but it is asynchronous and i faced problems

```
function GetLibraryActivities(libraryName, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/WorkflowDesigner/GetLibraryActivities/?libraryName=" + libraryName
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    });
}
```

then I tried to work with callback function, but it didn't work too.

```
function GetLibraryActivities(libraryName, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        'url': "/WorkflowDesigner/GetLibraryActivities/?libraryName=" + libraryName,
        'type': 'GET',
        'success': callback
    });
}
GetLibraryActivities("Petrophysics", function (data) {
    petrophysicsData = data
});
```

when I try to use `petrophysicsData` variable under the code it returns unidentified , I need a mean to call a function in synchronous way, any help will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Why not do the rest in the callback function?

Comment: You cannot `return data` from inside an async call's callback... Use callbacks or promises to call other callbacks/functions.

Comment: Do you want synchronous or serial?

Comment: because the returned data will be used in another place after some processing , and I call the function multiple times for different libraries.

Comment: what is difference between synchronous and serial I think both are the same

Comment: Please explain the broader aim, as this level of detailed code is probably not where the problem lies. Can you show more of the code using these function?

Comment: Need more details about error.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie simply I need write code such this 
petrophysicsData  = GetLibraryActivities(libraryName);

is this possible or not in javascript ?!!
and if possible how I code it ?!!

Comment: `GetLibraryActivities(libraryName, function(petrophysicsData){ DO SOMETHING WITH IT HERE});` using callbacks is the more likely syntax or returning promises something like: `GetLibraryActivities(libraryName).done(function(petrophysicsData){DO SOMETHINGS WITH IT HERE});`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main problem here is that you are trying to 'return' something from an AJAX callback. You cannot expect an Async AJAX function to return values to the script function that called it, because the function that called it moved on after the AJAX call started. That is the point of an Async call, it allows the javascript to move on and not have to wait for the server communication to complete.

The best way to handle this is to call all portions of a function in sequential order by using callbacks, never planning to use a return.

So, rather than returning `data` it would be best to instead call a function that processes `data` from within the callback function. It can be a little inconvenient, but when working with Async calls, it is best to assume that you can only go deeper into your call stack, rather than returning anything back out of it.

So, rather than your first option...you would want to do something like this instead...

```
function GetLibraryActivities(libraryName, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/WorkflowDesigner/GetLibraryActivities/?libraryName=" + libraryName
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        ProcessResults(data);
    });
}
```

Or, simply perform your processing within the callback.

Pre jQuery 1.8, there was the 'async' option, that would allow you to force Javascript to wait for the ajax call to process...but this locks up the browser while it is processing, and has since been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply return the Ajax promise like this:

```
function GetLibraryActivities(libraryName, callback) {
    return $.ajax({
        'url': "/WorkflowDesigner/GetLibraryActivities/?libraryName=" + libraryName,
        'type': 'GET'
    });
}
```

you can do this to use the value:

```
GetLibraryActivities("Petrophysics").done(function (data) {
    // do something with petrophysics data
});
```

and chain them "sequentially" with `then` like this:

```
GetLibraryActivities("Petrophysics").then(GetLibraryActivities("Astrophysics")).done(function(pertro, astro){
    // Do something with both results};
});
```

In this example both will load in parallel, but the done will only be called with both promises have completed (in any order).

If you have loads of these to load, you can use `$.when` to process multiple promises.